# How to get SSE for each cluster in k means?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I am using the sklearn.cluster KMeans package and trying to get SSE for each cluster. I understand `kmeans.inertia_` will give the sum of SSEs for all clusters. Is there any way to get SSE for each cluster in sklearn.cluster KMeans package?

I have a dataset which has 7 attributes and 210 observations. The number of cluster is 3 and would like to compute SSE for each cluster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this using a [KMeans](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) object. However, you can easily compute the sum of squared distances for each cluster yourself.

```
import numpy as np

# ...

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit(X)

cluster_centers = [X[kmeans.labels_ == i].mean(axis=0) for i in range(3)]

clusterwise_sse = [0, 0, 0]
for point, label in zip(X, kmeans.labels_):
    clusterwise_sse[label] += np.square(point - cluster_centers[label]).sum()
```

This snippet is not the most efficient way to do this since my goal was to present the concept clearly.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Do you know how to compute centroid of each cluster? `kmeans.cluster_centers_` gives the coordinates of cluster centers, but not be consistent with `labels_`

Comment: The [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) states that this could happen when the algorithm is stopped before convergence. If you are unhappy with the precision you could certainly recalculate it from the labels afterward. The centroid of a cluster is the point with the least average distance which can be found by a simple averaging operation.  I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

Basically there is a parameter for your 'k means' model which is called 'inertia_'
This parameter calculates the sum of squared errors and you can basically save it like in an array or so and can plot it as shown in the code below.

```
k = range(1,10)
sum_squared_errors = []

for i in k:
  model = KMeans(n_clusters = i)
  model.fit_predict(X)
  sum_squared_errors.append(model.inertia_)

plt.plot(k,sum_squared_errors)
plt.xlabel('K-Value')
plt.ylabel('Sum of Squared Errors')
```